# Playing movie files without the URL in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, video, resources, movie

Right now in my project I have the windows media player object, and I can get that to play movies on it by inputting the movie URL into the URL property. How do I get it to play a movie that is currently in my resources? Because when I transfer the executable file to my other laptop to test it it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, when you embed a video file into the application you only embed the data of it, and the extension gets stripped.
So in order to view it, you would need to copy it to a temporary directory and add the extension yourself, then play it from that location.

I haven't found a need to do such a thing since 2005, so visual studio may have made some changes.

Easiest way would be to have the video file you want played stored in the same location as your programs executable and simply refer to it using its name.

Comment: Since i couldn't remember as well as i would like, i found something that seems similar, with a little more detail and any missing steps.
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/434411/how-to-add-video-from-resources-of-visual-basic-2008